# .NET Action with nested Action questions

Tags: .net, lambda

I have next snippet:

```
public Action<Action<bool>> GetAction()
{
    return m => MyMethod(123, "string", m);
}

private void MyMethod(int someInteger, string someString, Action<bool> boolAction)
{
    // some work with int and string was done
    boolAction(true);
}
```

Could you please explain me why this work? I see that `Action<Action<bool>>` need some void method with **only one** parameter of `Action<bool>`. So what is wrong here with two first arguments?

Also it's not clear for me why we pass `m` into. How this lambda could be called in the `boolAction(true)`. What will happen there?

Any advice on this will be helpfull.

Comment: "So what is wrong here with two first arguments?" Why do you think that?

Comment: I think that `Action<Action<bool>>` need take only method with one argument in his signature (`Action<bool>`). But in my case I have `Action<int, string, Action<bool>>`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason that it shouldn't work. In line where lambda is created, C# is automatically infers which parameters your lambda will receive, from type of `GetAction` return value. To understand this code it's important that you see that you are not returning `m`, but you are returning

```
m => MyMethod(123, "string", m);
```

Therefore, `m` is of type `Action<bool>`, and above expression is of type `Action<Action<bool>>`, where inner Action is actually `m`.

I.e.

```
m => MyMethod(123, "string", m);
```

creates lambda expression which would correspond to method of this signature:

```
void _no_name(Action<bool> m) {
  MyMethod(123, "string", <delegate_to_no_name>);
}
```

From this part we see that `m` is `Action<bool>`, and `_no_name` is `Action<Action<bool>>`.

In the end you would use this code somehow like this probably:

```
Action<Action<bool>> action = GetAction();
action(x => MessageBox.Show("X of type bool is " + x.ToString()));
```

Effectively, our message box call delegate becomes the `m` parameter.

Comment: So why the above expression is of type `Action<Action<bool>>` and not `Action<int, string, Action<bool>>`?

Comment: Above expression is of type `Action<Action<bool>>` because that is what you declared it to be in your method definition. You are returning lambda expression, which is an Action. That action that you return takes another action as parameter. `m` is that parameter. If you had put `public Action<bool> GetAction`, `m` would be of type `bool`, and `m => MyAction(123, "string", m)` would be of type `Action<bool>`